# Foreach cycle on HTML form named as array

Tags: php, html, database, forms, foreach

Hello i have this html form with list of names from database.

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id_person, surname, firstname FROM persons ORDER BY surname,firstname");

$selected_persons= array(); 

echo "<select name='persons[]' multiple='multiple' size='7'>";
  while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) { 
     echo "<option value='".$result['id_person']."'";

     if (in_array($result['id_person'], $selected_persons)) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
     }

    echo ">".$result['surname']." ".$result['firstname']."</option>";
```

and i need foreach cycle which will return `id_person` of selected persons

Comment: Update your comment in the code in the question  by clicking edit button below your question...

Comment: sorry ... i didnt notice that button :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selected persons will be in `$_POST['persons']` (assuming the form's method is `POST`), so you can iterate over them with a foreach:

```
foreach($_POST['persons'] as $id_person)
{
    echo 'selected: ' . htmlspecialchars($id_person);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your combo will be multidimensional array i.e $_POST['persons'][], so use following code to retrieve selected values.

```
foreach($_POST['persons'][] AS $selected_person)
{
    echo $selected_person;
}
```